# Are all modules listed in a .vbp file visible to all the other .frm modules listed in the same file?

Tags: vb6

I am new to VB6. I happened to open a .vbp file and saw that it contained a list of items like

```
  Form=ABC.frm
  Module=PQR; PQR.bas
  Class=clsXYZ; XYZ.cls
```

My question is, does this mean that module PQR and clsXYZ are visible to ABC and it can access their public variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form ABC can see module PQR, but it will only be able to access variables or functions that are scoped as Public (or "worse", Global). Form ABC will be able to instantiate an object of class clsXYZ.

Comment: Friend also has the same visibility as Public in a project.